# Using C# REST API to send TriggeredSend email - created in Content Builder in SFMC in C# code

Tags: c#, rest, email, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am totally new to SalesForce Marketing cloud.

We have a “Triggered Send” created using “Content Builder” with an email body with HTML attribuites. For eg. %%=v(@EVENT)=%% Invitation
There is a Customer_key for this TriggerSendDefinition

I am using FuelSDK –  to TriggerSend this email.
I have NUget Package manager install Fuel SDK in my Visual studio 2019 project.
The App.config has the “clientId” and “clientSecret” values in the FuelSDK config section.
Here is my code below.

```
public void TestInvitationSend(string CustomerKey)
    {
        
        string myName = "John Adams";
        string myEvent = "13989";

        string fullurl = baseAPIAuthURL + AuthTokenUrl;   // Values passed in
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters.Add("clientId", clientId);
        parameters.Add("clientSecret",clientSecret);
        parameters.Add("accountId", "account123");

        **ETClient myclient = new ETClient(parameters);**
       
        TriggeredSendDefinition definition = new TriggeredSendDefinition();
        definition.CustomerKey = customerKey;

        //subscriber to whom email is sent
        Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber();
        subscriber.EmailAddress = myTest@test.com;
        subscriber.SubscriberKey = myTest@test.com;

        TriggeredSend triggeredsend = new TriggeredSend();
        triggeredsend.TriggeredSendDefinition = definition;
        triggeredsend.AuthStub = myclient;
        triggeredsend.CustomerKey = customerKey;
        triggeredsend.Subscribers = new Subscriber[] { subscriber };
        SendReturn results = triggeredsend.Send();
        Console.WriteLine("Send Status: " + results.Status.ToString());
          }
```

I am getting a 404 error at the line in “bold” when initializing myClient and unable to pass-in values dynamically. Could not find much documentation for email send through code.
Can you point me to some examples of TriggerSend emails using REST API ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest mocking up your API calls with Postman first, then implementing with an SDK.    The Postman collection is way more relevant than any of the SDKs, IMO. https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/collection/14448118-2835a976-010c-4548-92f8-f42c0382758e?ctx=documentation

Comment: Thanks very much. I will work on that and let you know,

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Thanks for your help earlier. I am able to receive a Triggered email using the C# code. I have set Attributes for the Subscriber and but email does not populate attribute values. I see the subscriber has attributes (thru debuging code). Pl help

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs. I am able to send a TriggeredSend Email thru code. I appreciate your help